# Calculating Daily Change and New Salespersons

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a SALES table with Person, Date and Qty:

```
Person    Date       Qty
Bob     2016-08-01    5
Bob     2016-08-02    2
Bob     2016-08-03    6
Bob     2016-08-04    4
Jim     2016-08-01    1
Jim     2016-08-02    3
Jim     2016-08-03    2
Jim     2016-08-04    2
Sheila  2016-08-03    9
Sheila  2016-08-04   12
```

I would like to produce 3 outputs

1) The Daily change in total Qty for the Persons who were selling the prior day:

```
  Date       Qty    Change     Pct Change
2016-08-01    0       0             0.00    
2016-08-02    5      -1           -16.66
2016-08-03    8       3            60.00
2016-08-04    18      1             5.88
```

Note that 8/1/16 is the first day in my dataset, so total = 0 since no SalesPerson was selling the prior day.  Also note that Sheila started selling on 8/3, which means here 8/3 sales do not figure into the 8/3 qty or change.  However, when determining the 8/4 change, Sheila's 8/3 sales of 9 units are used to determine the correct total change of 1 unite for 8/4.

2) I want to break out the totals for new SalesPersons each day on one line per day.  If no new Salespersons are added, then the date would show zeros.

```
 Date      New Qty
2016-08-01    6
2016-08-02    0
2016-08-03    9
2016-08-04    0
```

Since 8/1 was the first day of selling for anyone, both sales for Bob and Jim are included in the New Qty of 6 for 8/1.

3) The final output shows detail for #2, such as the date that a new SalesPerson started selling and the quantity they sold on that day.

```
  Date       Person  New Qty
2016-08-01    Bob       5
2016-08-01    Jim       1
2016-08-03    Sheila    9
```

Are these 3 outputs possible in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. It is all possible. First and second are a bit complex but possible to do.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempts.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LAG() if you are using sql server 2012 or above. You got the **"change"**. You can figure out the rest.

**Query #1:**

```
 SELECT
      dt.DateVal,
      SUM(CASE WHEN dt.PreviousQuota = 0 THEN 0 ELSE dt.PreviousQuotadd END)  Change
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
    Id,
    Person,
    DateVal,
    Qty,
     LAG(Qty, 1,0) OVER ( PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY DateVal) AS PreviousQuota ,
     LEAD(Qty, 1,0) OVER ( PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY DateVal) AS NextQuota  ,
    LAG(Qty, 1,0) OVER ( PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY DateVal) AS PreviousQuotad ,
    (Qty -  LAG(Qty, 1,0) OVER ( PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY DateVal)) AS PreviousQuotadd
    FROM Table1
    ) AS dt
```

Here is the [Fiddlle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e37b5/11) link.

Comment: Prabhath, SQL does not recognize dateval.  Is there an equivalent command for SQL Server 2012?

Comment: I am referring column "Date" in your table  as  DateVal. try the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e37b5/11

Answer (score 1):

I solved the following queries:

**Query #2:**

```
WITH CTE_1 AS 
 (Select DISTINCT Date FROM [master].[dbo].[Sales] GROUP BY Date)
, CTE_2 AS 
 (select Person,Date,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Person Order By Date) as RowNum, SUM(Qty) as  [PersonDailySum]
FROM [master].[dbo].[Sales]
GROUP BY Person,Date)
,CTE_3 AS(
SELECT T0.date, SUm([PersonDailySum]) As [New Qty]
FROM CTE_1 T0 
LEFT JOIN CTE_2 T1 
ON T0.Date = T1.date AND T1.RowNum = 1
GROUP BY T0.Date)
SELECT Date, ISNULL([New Qty],0) AS [New Qty] FROM CTE_3
```

**Query #3**

```
SELECT Date,Person,SUM([PersonDailySum]) AS [New Qty] FROM (
select Person,Date,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Person Order By Date) as RowNum, SUM(Qty) as  [PersonDailySum]
FROM [master].[dbo].[Sales]
GROUP BY Person,Date) T0
WHERE T0.RowNum = 1
GROUP BY Date,Person
```